# Is there a range data structure in Scala?

Tags: scala, range, rangeset

I'm looking for a way to handle ranges in Scala. 
What I need to do is:

given a set of ranges and a range(A) return the range(B) where range(A) intersect range (B) is not empty

given a set of ranges and a range(A) remove/add range(A) from/to the set of ranges.

given range(A) and range(B) create a range(C) = [min(A,B), max(A,B)]

I saw something similar in java - http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/RangeSet.html
Though `subRangeSet` returns only the intersect values and not the range in the set (or list of ranges) that it intersects with.

```
 RangeSet rangeSet = TreeRangeSet.create();
 rangeSet.add(Range.closed(0, 10));
 rangeSet.add(Range.closed(30, 40));
 Range range = Range.closed(12, 32);
 System.out.println(rangeSet.subRangeSet(range)); //[30,32] (I need [30,40])
 System.out.println(range.span(Range.closed(30, 40))); //[12,40]
```

Comment: if it's necessarily a range of integers, `scala.collection.immutable.Range` might do the trick?

Answer (score 6):

There is an `Interval[A]` type in the [spire math library](https://github.com/non/spire). This allows working with ranges of arbitrary types that define an `Order`. Boundaries can be inclusive, exclusive or omitted. So e.g. `(-∞, 0.0]` or `[0.0, 1.0)` would be possible intervals of doubles.

Here is a library [intervalset](https://github.com/rklaehn/intervalset) for working with sets of non-overlapping intervals ([IntervalSeq](https://github.com/rklaehn/intervalset/blob/master/IntervalSeq.md) or [IntervalTrie](https://github.com/rklaehn/intervalset/blob/master/IntervalTrie.md)) as well as maps of intervals to arbitrary values ([IntervalMap](https://github.com/rklaehn/intervalset/blob/master/IntervalMap.md)).

Here is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33998537/finding-overlapping-datetime-intervals-of-elements-in-multiple-lists/33998643#33998643) that describes how to use IntervalSeq with DateTime.

Note that if the type you want to use is 64bit or less (basically any primitive), IntervalTrie is *extremely fast*. See the [Benchmarks](https://github.com/rklaehn/intervalset/blob/master/IntervalTrie.md#benchmarks).

Answer (score 2):

As Tzach Zohar has mentioned in the comment, if all you need is range of Int - go for scala.collection.immutable.Range:

```
val rangeSet = Set(0 to 10, 30 to 40)
val r = 12 to 32
rangeSet.filter(range => range.contains(r.start) ||  range.contains(r.end))
```

If you need it for another underlying type - implement it by yourself, it's easy for your usecase.